# Should I break up long scanf to make it maintainable?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a file that has fixed-width columns that are a mix of 2 and 4 digit ints, some floats, and strings. All mixed together. The result is a scanf format that runs off the page...

```
fscanf(file, "%2d%2d%2d%2d%4d%4d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%2d%1s%1d%2d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%3d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%3d%1s%1d%3d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%5ld%1s%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%3d%1s%1d%3d%1s%1d%3d%1s%1d%2d%1s%1d",
```

And that doesn't even include the variable list!

Suggestions on how to make this maintainable? Should I just do several `scanf`s in a row? Or is there a canonical solution people use in this situation?

**UPDATE:** I had included the original data in my first post, but apparently clipped it out during an edit. The data in question is called TMY2, and you can find the definition and an example format string [here](http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/pubs/tmy2/tab3-2.html). There is also a newer format, TMY3, which uses CVS so I have many good examples of how to parse that.

Comment: I wouldn't even use `scanf()` for that.  How do you plan on handling data such as "02 1123..."?  Getting a space in your data will break things badly.  `scanf()` is nowhere near robust enough to use for real data parsing where data might be off a bit.

Comment: The question itself is a little opinion based, but you can break up a string into multiple strings. The compiler will concatenate them into a single string for you.

Comment: this example shows that you need to reconsider your idea.

Comment: looking by this horrible code, you parse your data statically so why do you bother about maintainable ? This code will it change in the futur ?

Comment: What kind of data and file is this? Where does it come from? What kind of program are you coding? How do you test scanning errors?

Comment: Your restricted  input such as `%1d` is problemmatical. If the user enters say `42` the ignored `2` does not go away: it is presented to the next format specifier.

Comment: "how to make this maintainable?" is possible, yet more info needed. 
 Post some sample lines of input and a complete lines of code.

Comment: I would expand on @AndrewHenle 's comment: I wouldn't use scanf for anything!  IMO, the best way to make your code maintainable is to stop using scanf.  If you have a problem for which scanf is appropriate, then you're probably better of implementing a solution in `perl`.

Comment: As I noted in the update, this is the *suggested solution* in the original government document. Which is precisely why I asked if I should do it that way!

Comment: The specification of the data at http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/pubs/tmy2/tab3-2.html is, to be blunt, utter !(%&#@!% crap.  If the data is written using the C format string given, **it can't be read using that same format string**.  What happens if you pass the `int` value `1` to the `%2d` format string?  You get a leading space and it's now broken.  What happens if you pass `100` to `%2d`?  The "fixed width" format is broken.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - they supply the data too, it does not have these problems.

Comment: *they supply the data too, it does not have these problems.* You mean **yet**.  Or until the day it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> file that has fixed-width columns that are a mix ....
>   how to make this maintainable ?

Step 1, read the *line* into a generous buffer with `fgets()`.  Do not use `fscanf()` [@Andrew Henle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804428/should-i-break-up-long-scanf-to-make-it-maintainable/49807580#comment86623681_49804428)

```
#define MY_BUF_N 400
char buf[MY_BUF_N * 2];  // make buffer 2x aticipated max size
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, file) == NULL) {
   Handle_EOF_or_Error();
}
```

Identify groups based on recurring patterns:

```
#define FMT_PRE "%2d%2d%2d%2d%4d%4d"
#define FMT_5   "%4ld%1s%1d"
#define FMT_4   "%4d%1s%1d"
#define FMT_3   "%4d%1s%1d"
#define FMT_2   "%4d%1s%1d"
#define FMT_MID "%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d"
```

Use *string literal* concatenation.  [@jxh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804428/should-i-break-up-long-scanf-to-make-it-maintainable/49807580#comment86623946_49804428)

```
#define FMT_ALL FMT_PRE \
        FMT_4 FMT_4 FMT_4 FMT_4 FMT_4 FMT_4 \
        FMT_2 FMT_2 FMT_4 FMT_4 FMT_3 FMT_4 \
        FMT_4 FMT_4 FMT_3 FMT_3 FMT_4 FMT_5 \
        FMT_MID \
        FMT_3 FMT_3 FMT_3 FMT_2
```

Use `" %n"` to test if the entire scan succeeded

```
int n = 0;
sscanf(FMT_ALL " %n", ...
  ...
  ...  /*  variable list laid out like the format statements. */
  ...
  &n);
```

Test `n`

```
// Did scan reach the end?
if (n == 0) {
  Handle_incomplete_scan();
}
// Was there any remaining junk? 
if (buf[n] != '\0') {
  Handle_junk_at_the_end();
}
```

Add additional  tests to validate the objects are in range.

---

In general, I would re-write. [@PeterJ_01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/peterj-01)  After step 1 with `fgets()`,   parse the  data sequentially using helper functions employing `strtol()`, etc.

```
size_t i = 0;  // Index in buffer
if (parse_int(&object1, buf, &i, min_value, max_value)) error();
if (parse_int(&object1, buf, &i, min_value, max_value)) error();
...
if (parse_string(object7, sizeof object7, buf, &i)) error();
....
if (parse_long(&object12, buf, &i, min_value, max_value)) error();
...
```

Comment: That is a superb answer! I am implementing now.

Comment: Note that this code can't handle an input of " 123 445...", where the values started as 1, 23, 4, and 45.  `scanf()` will read that as 12, 3, 44, with the next value dependent on what's in the fifth data element.

Comment: @AndrewHenle True, yet various particulars of valid and invalid input were unclear until OP later added a link after this answer - will review.

Comment: @chux in the case of a file that was saved on DOS/Win, the scanf will ignore the CR. Is that OK, or should I do anything more explicit to handle it?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz All the format specifiers used here consume optional leading white space including CR.

Comment: Ahh, ok. I have not been able to break up the format string - clang complains about the syntax of the line breaks - but the system is working fine. I've implemented the TMY3 as well (which was much easier) so I'm off to the races.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Concerning "clang complains about the syntax of the line breaks": insure there is nothing after the \ in lines like `"   FMT_MID \"` other than the line feed.

Answer (score 1):

The best options would be:

1. Use multiple scanfs, to each variable so it would be much easier to read the code and you would be certain that it wouldnt crash (Problem: a lot of lines just for scanfs, not very elegant);
2. Pass all those things as arguments for main, then you would only need to work with the argv, much easier to use and much more elegant (Problem: the user would need to know everything the program needs upfront, not very user friendly);

Hope it helps :)

Comment: 1) Is pointless and no improvement. 2) would be a completely different program structure and has its own problems. It also is not syntactical identical to the `scanf`. Summary: a bad answer.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're dealing with a specified data from the document at http://rredc.nrel.gov/solar/pubs/tmy2/tab3-2.html, you can't safely use `scanf()` at all.

Because that "specification" is broken.  Badly.  It does not specify how data shall be placed in each field.  Data can be left-justified with trailing spaces, right-justified with leading spaces, and right-justified with leading zeros.

All of those fit the "specification".  And there's no way to write one `scanf()` format string that can handle all those possibilities.

To be blunt, whoever wrote that "specification" is incompetent.

If the data is written using something like `sprintf()` and the C format string given:

```
(%2d%2d%2d%2d%4d%4d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s
%1d%4d%1s%1d%2d%1s%1d%2d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%3d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%3d
%1s%1d%3d%1s%1d%4d%1s%1d%5ld%1s%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%1d%3d%1s
%1d%3d%1s%1d%3d%1s%1d%2d%1s%1d)
```

it can not be safely read with `scanf()`.  For example, this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 99;
    int c = 34;

    char buffer[ 128 ];

    sprintf( buffer, "%2d%2d%2d", a, b, c );

    printf( "a: %d\nb: %d\nc: %d\n", a, b, c );

    printf( "String: '%s'\n", buffer );

    sscanf( buffer, "%2d%2d%2d", &a, &b, &c );

    printf( "a: %d\nb: %d\nc: %d\n", a, b, c );

    return( 0 );
}
```

produces this output:

```
a: 1
b: 99
c: 34
String: ' 19934'
a: 19
b: 93
c: 4
```

Note that the values don't match.

Again:  you can't use `scanf()` on that data.  At all.

Comment: > If the data is written using something like sprintf() 
The original data comes from Fortran, AFAIK.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Well, if your standard of performance is "Yeah, your data fits the spec, but we hadn't seen it that way before, so we're now broken.", then go ahead and use `scanf()`.  But be aware that's how you wind up with systems that have nine fives reliability.  Then you get called in at 3 AM and get to finally do it reliably under a lot of time pressure.